# Returning an Object with Non-Disposed Memory Stream causes memory leaks?

Tags: c#, dispose, using

I've come across a routine that does something like this:

```
static public Bitmap byte2bmp(byte[] BitmapData)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(BitmapData);
    return (new Bitmap(ms));
}
```

I'm worried this might not be the best recommended approach. Does the ms gets disposed properly in this scenario?

Or would it be better to assign the result to a temporary Bitmap, dispose of the stream, and then return the temp object?

```
static public Bitmap byte2bmp(byte[] BitmapData)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(BitmapData);
    Bitmap temp=new Bitmap(ms);
    ms.Dispose();
    return (temp);
}
```

I was hoping the "using" might be used in this scenario, but am not sure it would behave properly or not:

```
static public Bitmap byte2bmp(byte[] BitmapData)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(BitmapData))
    {
    return (new Bitmap(ms));
    }
}
```

What is the most effective/proper solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in worrying that the first approach will fail to dipose `ms`. As a matter of good practice, you should always call the `Dispose` method on objects that implement `IDisposable`.

**I recommend adopting the last approach. You can be confident that a `using` statement will dispose of the object as expected even if you return in the middle of it.**

Here's how the code would break down during run time: First, the return expression will be evaluated, then the try-finally block (for which the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is simply syntactic sugar) will be executed, and finally the method will return.

The only case in which you might encounter issues with returning in the middle of a `using` statement is [if you return the variable from the `using` statement itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228521/return-an-object-created-by-using). Of course, this would cause issues anyway if you retained any reference to the variable beyond the scope of the `using` block.

Also see: [Best practice regarding returning from using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223865/best-practice-regarding-returning-from-using-blocks)

Comment: @LukeH: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The C# spec indicates that the return expression will be evaluated first before the `finally` block that handles the disposal of the stream object, so whatever the `Bitmap` constructor decided to do would be irrelevant.

Comment: I was wrong, but not in that way. The `Bitmap` class *will potentially break* if you close/dispose the stream. From MSDN: *"You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the `Bitmap`."* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx

Comment: @LukeH: Ah, okay. I'd never noticed that before. What reason do you now have to believe that wouldn't cause any problems and/or that the fact the above code works isn't simply relying on an implementation detail?

Comment: In my original comment I said that the `Bitmap` class shouldn't/wouldn't do this because it's bad practice. I was wrong because it does, unfortunately. (Presumably it holds a reference to the stream internally and then re-uses it later, rather than eagerly converting the stream to a `byte[]` or whatever when the constructor is first called.)

Comment: Would using a  return (new Bitmap(ms).Clone(rect,pixFormat)) "bypass" that requirement of having the stream open during the original BMP lifetime?